# How to use Multi Choice Field in Django 2.0

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-orm

This picture below illustrate all what I want to implement in the Database. Please I don't know how to connect the Unit and Course_code fields in the model with each course in the choice field.... Students can enroll all Courses in the Turple
model.py[image: MultiChoiceField]

```
class Course(models.Model):
    COURSES_CHOICES = (
        ('analysis', 'Analysis'),
        ('numerical', 'Numerical'),
        ('philosophy', 'Philosophy'),
    )

    course_names = models.Charfield(choices=COURSES_CHOICES, null=True,)
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    couse_unit = models.intergerField()

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
```

I dont know if am right with my model.py... Am still a learner in Django

Comment: I think that the question is not clear, exactly what is your question?

Comment: I want to be able to have a collection of data as it is on the image and each line there will be a MultiChoiceField where students can register more than one courses at illustrate in image above... The Unit, Code, and Choicefield they are different fields on the same model

Comment: when printing my Choicefield i want to be able have the Unit and course_code on the same line with each courses in the choice field... Your contribution is highly welcome... thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve what you want to do.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=30)
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        to='Course',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```